# Javascript error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'branchei' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

i have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var b=document.update.branchei;
   function selectItemByValue(b, <%=branche%>){

for(var i=0; i < b.options.length; i++)
{
  if(b.options[i].value == <%=branche%>)
    b.selectedIndex = i;
}
 }

 </script>
```

'update' is the name of the form and 'branchei' is the name of the selectbox.

Comment: If multiple forms are there then you cannot use it like this, you should use `document.forms["update"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that

```
 var b = document.getElementsByName("branchei")[0];
```

Or that

```
var b = document.getElementsByName("branchei");
```

ps, why dont jQuery?

Comment: thank you the error is now gone but still can't get the element selected

Comment: @Hbib okay, so - can u tellm what is your goal ? what u want get in finish?

Comment: i have a selectbox with options and a String variable(branche) i want to test if one of the options' value equals 'branche' then the elemnt get selected. all of this when the page get opened

Comment: i don't know jQuery very well but if u have a solution give me

Comment: It will be more easier with jQuery, i create fiddle for u now

Comment: it's not exactly like that, i want it depending on the value of the text entered it goes and sees if one of the option.value equals the text then that option gets selected

Comment: can u edit it the way it works with pre defined String instead of entering the text manually

Comment: im dont understand - but when it will be triggering?

Comment: at the opening of the page, the text it will be testing on is preloaded from database